# Issue obtaining a running total percentage difference between dates

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I'm having an issue with a query, which is turning into multiple views and a full procedure in order
to generate a table to show a variance from one day to the next.
To be honest, under SQL Server, I can accomplish this with a single query.
However, under Oracle 11g, it is mind-numbingly difficult to do the same thing, and to top it off the queries 
run extemely slow.  It now takes in excess of 5 minutes to run my query, and it DOESNT WORK.

I have a table of data

```
DATE        SERVICE     ENV     RESPONSES
15-NOV-2016     PROD        T1      4793
15-NOV-2016     PROD        U1      3245
15-NOV-2016     PROD        X1      4984
14-NOV-2016     PROD        T1      5812
14-NOV-2016     PROD        U1      3918
14-NOV-2016     PROD        X1      3282
13-NOV-2016     PROD        T1      11231
13-NOV-2016     PROD        U1      1564
13-NOV-2016     PROD        X1      2816
```

Note: This data goes back several years, and covers 6 environments

For the report, I need to generate a resultset that looks like this,

```
DATE        ENV T1      U1  X1  TOTAL   VARIANCE
20161115    PROD    4793    3245    4984    14022   +7.76%
20161114    PROD    5812    3918    3282    13012   -16.65%
20161113    PROD    11231   1564    2816    15611   +9.13%
```

This report goes out, when there is a variance greater than +/- 10%

Additionally, only want to send 3-5 rows, rather than the entire view.
I attempted to use partitioning, but it slowed my query to a crawl, and didn't generate the required data.

The design currently involves the creation of 6 separate views to join to the main table to pivot the data
But, I can't seem to get the query right to generate the Variance.
The variance is computed as ((current date total / yesterday's total) - 1) * 100
  or ((13012 / 15611) - 1.00) x 100 = -16.65

Each view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW USAGE_T1
(
   DATEREF,
   REALM,
   TOTAL
)
AS
   SELECT DATE, ENV, TOTAL
    FROM USAGE_COUNT
    WHERE ENV = 'T1';
```

This query builds out the table, but missing the variance

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(base.ENDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') AS DATEREF
    , base.ENV
    , T1.TOTAL AS "T1"
    , U1.TOTAL AS "U1"
    , X1.TOTAL AS "X1"
    , NVL(T1.TOTAL, 0) + NVL(U1.TOTAL,0) + NVL(X1.TOTAL,0) AS "TOTAL"
FROM USAGE base
LEFT JOIN USAGE_T1 T1
  ON T1.DATEREF = TO_CHAR(base.ENDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
LEFT JOIN USAGE_U1 U1
  ON U1.DATEREF = TO_CHAR(base.ENDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
LEFT JOIN USAGE_X1 X1
  ON X1.DATEREF = TO_CHAR(base.ENDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
WHERE base.ENV = 'PROD'
GROUP BY base.ENV, base.ENDDATE, T1.TOTAL, U1.TOTAL, X1.TOTAL
ORDER BY base.ENDDATE DESC;
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you need, I think:

```
with t (dat, env, service, responses) as (
select to_date('15-NOV-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),     'PROD',        'T1',      '4793' from dual union all
select to_date('15-NOV-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),     'PROD',        'U1',      '3245' from dual union all
select to_date('15-NOV-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),     'PROD',        'X1',      '4984' from dual union all
select to_date('14-NOV-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),     'PROD',        'T1',      '5812' from dual union all
select to_date('14-NOV-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),     'PROD',        'U1',      '3918' from dual union all
select to_date('14-NOV-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),     'PROD',        'X1',      '3282' from dual union all
select to_date('13-NOV-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),     'PROD',        'T1',      '11231' from dual union all
select to_date('13-NOV-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),     'PROD',        'U1',      '1564' from dual union all
select to_date('13-NOV-2016', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),     'PROD',        'X1',      '2816' from dual)
select tt.*, (total / lag(total, 1, null) over (order by dat) - 1) * 100 variance
  from (select to_char(dat, 'yyyymmdd') dat, t1, x1, u1, t1 + x1 + u1 total
          from t
         pivot (sum(responses) for service in ('T1' t1, 'X1' x1, 'U1' u1))
        ) tt;
```

Here: `with t` construction - source data, then interior query - pivot to put in one row data for different services, then in outer query function `lag` calculates previous row value. For more details, see documentation on [lag function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) and [pivot query](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html).

**Update**
How `lag` works: `lag` takes value of previous row. First argument is name of a column with data to take, second - count of row from current (1 take previous, 2 - 2 rows before, etc.), third - default value if there is no previous row. Order of rows is defined by order clause (`order by dat` above). To change direction of data shift, change sort order (asc/desc) of use function `lead`, which returng value of next row (almost the same as `lag`).

Comment: That worked 90%.  Thank you, it greatly simplified my queries and cleaned things up a bit.  Two issues, the variance was the inverse of what was needed, and the other, the variance value is showing up on the wrong row.  The first issue I resolved by wrapping (1/(total / lag(total, 1, null) over (order by dat) - 1) * 100. But the other has stumped me. Any idea how to move the variance value up a row?

Comment: @AllanL Updated answer

Comment: Thank you!!  I read up on the LAG and found LEAD, which adjusted everything nicely.  A really appreciate the speedy and very helpful response.  And it's quick!!